# Prove that $f'(x)g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g$ be continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$, suppose $g$ is nonnegative on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$. Suppose further that $g(a) = 0$ and $g(b) = 0$, and that

$$\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx = 0$$

Prove that,
 $$f'(x)g(x) = 0$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 3):

By integration by parts, $\int f'(x) g(x) dx = f(x) g(x) - \int f(x) g'(x) dx$.

So $0 = \int_a^b f'(x) g(x) dx = f(a) g(a) - f(b)g(b) - \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx$

Since $g(a) = g(b) = 0$, it's clear that the first two terms are $0$.  The third term in the expression, we are given, is also $0$: $\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx = 0$.

We have $\int_a^b f'(x) g(x) dx = 0$, and $f'(x) g(x) \ge 0$ and is continuous, so we might conclude here that $f'(x) g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

---

If we cannot use the theorem that a nonnegative continuous function whose integral over some interval is identically $0$ over that integral, then we may proceed as follows:

By assumptions, $g(x) \ge 0$ and $f'(x) \ge 0$.  Suppose $f'(c) > 0$ and $g(c) > 0$ for some fixed point $c \in ( a,b)$.  By continuity, $f'(x) > 0$ and $g(x) > 0$ for some neighborhood $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$.  So $$\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} f'(x) g(x) dx > 0$$

By nonnegativity of the product $f'(x) g(x)$, it follows that $$\int_a^{c-\epsilon} f'(x) g(x) dx , \int_{c+\epsilon}^b f'(x) g(x) dx \ge 0$$

So $\displaystyle \int_a^b f'(x) g(x) dx = \int_a^{c-\epsilon} f'(x) g(x) dx + \int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} f'(x) g(x) dx + \int_{c+\epsilon}^b f'(x) g(x) dx > 0$

Comment: You wrote `\in` instead of `\int` @BabyDragon}

Comment: @andrewsalmon To use the integration by parts theorem, f' and g' have to be integrable on [a,b]. Is that given somewhere in the question?

Comment: Oh my. And it is too late to edit. Here it is retyped: 
*So you have proved that $\int^b_a f′(x)g(x)=0$. I think that the OP wants to know that $f′g=0$. One must use the fact that f is increasing (what does this say about $f′$) and that $g$ is non-negetive.* @Jaime one can always conclude that of $\int^b_a H(x)=0$ and $H(x)\geq 0$, and $H$ continuous that $H=0$.

Comment: @BabyDragon Can I conclude that f'(x) and g'(x) are integrable because f(x) and g(x) are continuously differentiable by FTC?

Comment: Yes that is certainly true.

Comment: I finished writing up the answer.  I need to proofread my work better.

Comment: It might be sufficient, after you've shown that $\int_{a}^{b} f'(x) g(x)\, dx =0$, simply to say (because the OP might have a theorem available that says) that integral of a nonnegative continuous function over an interval is $0$ iff that function is identically zero.